# How to change the default folder used for documents scanned with Windows Fax and Scan?

Tags: windows-8.1, scanner

When I scan a document with Windows Fax and Scan on Windows 8.1, the resulting file is automatically saved in the "Scanned Documents" subfolder of the "Documents" folder. How to change this location?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Backup all the scanned files you need to keep
- Open the automatic Scanned Documents folder and click on the address bar to copy its full location. It should look like `C:\Users\BillGates\Documents\Scanned Documents`
- Go back to the `Documents` folder and delete `Scanned Documents`
- Open a command prompt window. On Windows 8.1, you can do this by using the shortcut keys <kbd>⊞</kbd> (Windows key) + <kbd>S</kbd> and typing **cmd**. On Windows 7 and Windows 10, type **cmd** in the start menu search bar
- Enter the following command and press enter, where `C:\scans` is the directory you want to be used to save new scanned files:

  mklink /d "C:\Users\BillGates\Documents\Scanned Documents" C:\scans

This creates a [linked folder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) (symlink, not a shortcut). It  acts like a normal folder but is actually located in a different place. When the scan software saves into its default location, the files will actually be saved into `C:\scans`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and found this thread. Creating a hard link is not the best solution for me, so I decided to search in the registry for a string and found these entries:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Photo
>   Acquisition\**DestinationMru**
>
> **"MruEntry0"**
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Photo
>   Acquisition\**Scanner**
>
> **"FilenameTemplate"**
>
> **"VideoFilenameTemplate"**
>
> **"RootDirectory"**

I changed the value of all 4 keys and it worked! It was something like `E:\Scans` before and `R:\M_SCANS` after.

If your default directory is somewhere in your documents folder there might be a name like `%blahblah%`, which is where your variable userpath points to.

I've tested that under Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: It's nice to know that you've found another solution that fits your needs. I still use symlinks for that and other issues.

Comment: Excellent solution. In my Windows 7 Professional registry, the `MruEntry0` key had the hexadecimal value `27`, so I left it alone. I only had to change `FilenameTemplate` and `VideoFilenameTemplate` to get it to work.

Comment: Does this work on Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10, just right-click on the Documents folder in File Explorer and select Move. Move it to the desired location by moving or without moving existing files. Fax & Scanner will now scan to the new location.

Comment: I used the right-click and move method for my Windows 10 64-bit PC and it worked perfectly. Thanks.